# How to scrape a website behind a paywall

Tags: python, web-scraping

I wish to scrape news articles of the local newspaper. The archive is behind a paywall and I have a paid account, how would I go about automating the input of my credentials?

Comment: Did you check the TOS of your account? Almost certainly bulk scraping is forbidden...

Comment: Can you post some code that you have tried? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Scrapy (See the [Tutorial](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html%20Tutorial)) using FormRequest to send data via HTTP POST (See the [Example](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#topics-request-response-ref-request-userlogin%20Example))

```
# Install scrapy : pip install Scrapy
# Create structure with : scrapy startproject my_project
# Create ./my_project/spiders/my_spider.py
#   use something like this inside my_spider.py:

class LoginSpider(Spider):
name = 'example.com'
start_urls = ['http://www.example.com/users/login.php']

def parse(self, response):
    return [FormRequest.from_response(response,
                formdata={'username': 'john', 'password': 'secret'},
                callback=self.after_login)]

def after_login(self, response):
    # check login succeed before going on
    if "authentication failed" in response.body:
        self.log("Login failed", level=log.ERROR)
        return

    # continue scraping with authenticated session...
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this may answer the question, [it is preferred](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts here, providing the link as reference. That way "link rot" does not result in losing valuable contributions.

Comment: Thanks for introducing me to scrapy, I think is just what i was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access page behind paywall directly because that page may require some authentication data like session or cookies. So you have to first create these data and store it so that when you pass request to secure pages you pass require data as part of request and also have authentication session data.

To get authentication data you should scrape login page first. Get the session info,cookies of login page and pass login input as a request (get or post based on form action type) to action page. Once you will be logged in store authentication data and use this to scrape pages behind paywall.